# Re-assign value tag after first form submission?

Tags: java, forms, struts2, jstl, struts

Assume I have the following class

```
public class Account {

  private Long id;
  private String username;
  private String password;

  // getters + constructor

}
```

The following action class

```
public MyAction extends ActionSupport {

  private CoreService service;

  private long id;
  private String username;
  private String password;

  private Account account;

  public String loadAccount() {
    account = service.getAccountById(id);
    return SUCCESS;
  }

  public String updateAccount() {
    service.updateAccount(account);
    return SUCCESS;
  }
  // getters + setters
}
```

I use the loadAccount() method to populate the form's fields.

And my form:

```
<form action="update_account" method="post">
      <label for="username">New username</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" value="${account.username}" id="username" placeholder="Enter name" required>

      <label for="password">New password</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter new password" required>
</form>
```

Now, assume the user will write down a new username but the validation fails. The value inside 'username' textfield will be reset to account's username. I want to change my program and make it initially load account's username but then if validation fails it will load the last input.

Comment: You only need to change an expression, then it will keep the last value.

Comment: Will it still initially load my account's username?

Comment: Yes, if you set it to the field.

Comment: I am a little bit confused. Could you please tell me which expression should be changed?

Comment: The expression `${account.username}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code for displaying a field

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="${username}" id="username" placeholder="Enter name" required>
```

then a method to set it after loading

```
public String loadAccount() {
  account = service.getAccountById(id);
  setUsername(account.getUserName());
  return SUCCESS;
}
```